# pgadmin4 command keep running and process watcher won't go away

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I was trying to follow the instructions from [postgresqltutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/) to load a sample database into postgresql using pgadmin. But after the database was restored(since I can query data from the database), the process watcher just won't go away, and it keeps saying that the command is "running"(as of this writing, it has been running for over 400 thousands seconds, but the size of the sample database is just a few megabytes). Reboot and reinstallation couldn't fix the problem.

Here are some screen shots:

[image]

And when I click "click here for details":

[image]

I am using postgresql 9.6 with pgadmin4 on windows 10. So what's going on here? Is it a bug? How can I get rid of the process watcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in pgAdmin4 & reported,
https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1679

Comment: Yes, and I've just received a reply from the pgadmin mailing list which confirmed that it's a bug. The reply also says if anyone encounter the problem and "can afford to loose the server-list from pgAdmin 4, you can delete the configuration file for pgAdmin 4 found under '%APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db'."

Comment: sadly that issue link only works for registered users - and I have tried hard but not managed to register :-(

Comment: finally realized the username was not the email address and managed to log in to postgresql.org :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with posgresql 9.5 and pgAdmin4 on Windows 7. I solved it without loosing server list by opening %APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db file with SQLite Manager (Firefox Add-on) and deleting all entries from the 'process' table.

Answer (score 2):

close pgAdmin, restart the system, open %APPDATA% and erase the folder pgAdmin and the pgAdmin is Ready to start without errors.

Greetings